# Laravel How not to Rewrite the Same code again

Tags: laravel, function, duplicates

I have a model, called Tours and controller ToursController which uses restful methods (index, show, store, edit, update etc).

Now I have this code:

```
$names = request()->get('names');
$lastnames = request()->get('lastnames');
$hotels = request()->get('hotel');
```

both in Store and Update. So i duplicate the same code twice. And this is only one exmaple of duplicated code.

I want to create a function "getEverythingFromRequest()"

which I can use in both Store and Update methods. Something like:

```
public function store (Request $request) {

getEverythingFromRequest();

dd($names[3];

}


public function store (Request $request) {

getEverythingFromRequest();

dd($hotels[2];

}
```

How can I do it? Globally, how can I avoid re-writing the same code in Controller?

Comment: have you tried `firstOrCreate` method ? see  docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates

Comment: good method, thank you, I'll use it. But my question is more wider: how not to write code twice?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to solve this. One way would be to create a repo that extracts the arrays from your request. (I updated my code to use injection).

**Controller**

```
public function store (GuestsRepository $repo, Request $request) {

  dd($repo->names);

}
```

**Repository**

```
<?php

namespace App;

class GuestsRepository
{
    public $names;
    public $lastnames;
    public $hotels;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->names = request()->get('names');
        $this->lastnames = request()->get('lastnames');
        $this->hotels = request()->get('hotel');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, whoacowboy. Could you point to other ways as well?)

Comment: Sure, you could do this a bunch of ways, what are you looking to do besides just reuse code?